# SQL decode column value to another column

Tags: sql

I am using PL/SQL 12.
I want to decode a column value to match another column value. I take the highest value of the the columns `SP_RANK` and `MOODY_RANK` and call it `RANK`. I want this column to instead of values have the corresponding value in either `SP` or `MOODYS` depending on which value is highest.

Below my code and a snippet of the data.

```
SELECT rv.updat
  , rv.instrumentid
  , greatest(nvl(rv.sp_rank, '-1')
  , nvl(rv.moody_rank, '-1')) AS "Rank"
  , rv.sp
  , rv.moodys
  , rv.SP_Rank
  , rv.Moody_Rank
FROM ci.ratings_view rv
ORDER BY rv.updat ASC
```

Table:

```
INSTRUMENTID | UPDAT      | Rank | SP  | MOODYS | SP_RANK | MOODY_RANK 
-------------+------------+------+-----+--------+---------+-----------
0203041      | 26/09/2019 | 100  | AAA | Aaa    | 100     | 100       
0203378      | 26/09/2019 | 100  | AAA | Aaa    | 100     | 100        
0203734      | 26/09/2019 | 100  | AAA | Aaa    | 100     | 100       
0204196      | 26/09/2019 | 100  | AAA | Aaa    | 100     | 100       
0204277      | 26/09/2019 | 100  | AAA | Aaa    | 100     | 100       
0413194      | 26/09/2019 | 75   | A   | NR     | 75      | -1        
0413216      | 26/09/2019 | 75   | A   | NR     | 75      | -1        
0413240      | 26/09/2019 | 75   | A   | NR     | 75      | -1        
0460583      | 26/09/2019 | 100  | AAA | NR     | 100     | -1        
0460656      | 26/09/2019 | 100  | AAA | NR     | 100     | -1        
0471534A     | 26/09/2019 | 100  | AAA | WR     | 100     | -1        
0491438      | 26/09/2019 | -1   | NR  | NR     | -1      | -1
```

So instead of `100` it should say `AAA` and instead of `75` `A`, etc.

Comment: Can you show us what is your expected result ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `CASE` statement:

```sql
select 
  rv.updat, 
  rv.instrumentid, 
  greatest(nvl(rv.sp_rank,'-1'), 
  nvl(rv.moody_rank,'-1')) as "Rank",
  rv.sp, 
  rv.moodys, 
  rv.SP_Rank, 
  rv.Moody_Rank, 
  CASE 
    WHEN COALESCE(rv.moody_rank, -1) > COALESCE(rv.SP_Rank, -1) THEN rv.moodys 
    ELSE rv.SP 
  END AS NewRank
from ci.ratings_view rv
order by rv.updat asc
```

You may need to add some extra logic to handle ties -- i.e. which rank to use (SP or Moodys)